# Calling Google Drive API returns Invalid_grant OAuth2

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, google-sheets, node-modules

**SOLVED!**

The problem was not my code. I'd manually set the time on my Linux Server, which meant that Google's server refused giving me access. I used following command on my Server to set time: `ntpdate 0.europe.pool.ntp.org`

**Original Issue:**

I'm currently trying to develop a small script in NodeJS, which reads some values from a Google Spreadsheet, and write it to a file in JSON format.

The code is functioning without any problems on my Mac, but after upload to a Ubuntu 14.04.4, some of the functions from the 'google-spreadsheet' module is not working and returns undefined.

I'm not 100% sure, whether there is a problem with the node module, or if there is something wrong with my code.

The code which does the call:

```
var GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
var fs = require('fs');

function scheduleBidding(sheetSecretKey) {
    this.sheetKey = sheetSecretKey;
}

scheduleBidding.prototype.getBiddingHeaders = function (filePrefix) {
var doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(this.sheetKey);
var sheet;
var daysSinceYearStart = getDaysIntoYear();
var localSheetKey = this.sheetKey;
var biddingObject = new Object();
var filePath = filePrefix+"staticConfigFiles/googleApiKey";
console.log(filePath);
fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    creds = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(creds);
    doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds, function (err) {
        if(err) throw err;
        doc.getInfo(function (err, info) {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(info);
            sheet = info.worksheets[0];
            var numberOfColumns = sheet.colCount;
            sheet.getCells({
                'min-row': 1,
                'max-row': 1,
                'min-col': 2,
                'max-col': numberOfColumns,
                'return-empty': true
            }, function(err, cells) {
                sheet.getRows({
                    offset: 1,
                    limit: 366
                }, function( err, rows ){
                    yesterdaysBid = rows[daysSinceYearStart-2];
                    todaysBidding = rows[daysSinceYearStart-1];
                    cells.forEach(function (listItem, indexArray) {
                        columnName = cells[indexArray].value;
                        var functionName = String(columnName.toLowerCase());
                        functionName = functionName.replace(/\s/g, '').replace(":", "");
                        biddingObject[columnName] = {
                            "yesterdaysBid": yesterdaysBid[functionName],
                            "todaysBid": todaysBidding[functionName]
                        };
                        newFileName = filePrefix+"scheduleData/"+localSheetKey+".json";
                        prettyJson = JSON.stringify(biddingObject);
                        fs.writeFile(newFileName, prettyJson);
                        console.log("ScheduleBidding JSON has been updated");
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});

function getDaysIntoYear() {
    var todaysDate = new Date();
    var daysAgo;

    //
    returnDays = parseInt(todaysDate.getDate())+daysAgo;
    return returnDays;
}
};
```

I recieve the following exception when I execute the script on my Ubuntu server:

```
    Error: invalid_grant
www-0     at Request._callback (/SomePath/node_modules/google-spreadsheet/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/gtoken/lib/index.js:215:34)
www-0     at Request.self.callback (/SomePath/node_modules/google-spreadsheet/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/gtoken/node_modules/request/request.js:187:22)
www-0     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
www-0     at Request.<anonymous> (/SomePath/node_modules/google-spreadsheet/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/gtoken/node_modules/request/request.js:1044:10)
www-0     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
www-0     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/SomePath/node_modules/google-spreadsheet/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/gtoken/node_modules/request/request.js:965:12)
www-0     at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
www-0     at _stream_readable.js:920:16
www-0     at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:459:13)
```

Thanks in advance for the help. Let me know, if any information is missing.

Comment: You have run `npm install` right? It looks like you have. Maybe check the version you have installed on your mac and change the `package.json` entry to match that version exactly.

Comment: Yes. I can post my package.json file if that would be helpful? I am although able to see the function which I am supposed to use in /node_modules/google-spreadsheet/index.js via the nano command.

Comment: The version of the google-spreadsheet module, and the version listed in the package.json is a match.

Comment: can you provide the line 24 of your scheduleBidding.js regarding `www-0 (err): at /somePath/ServerObjects/scheduleBidding.js:24:17`

Comment: It is the following call: doc.getInfo(function (err, info) {...}); I am able to read the object "doc" and if I log it, I am able to see the functions it contains. Although when I call it, I get the exception.

Comment: try to comment this line and see if anythings works...  
/node_modules/google-spreadsheet/index.js:114:24     
 if (google_auth.expires > +new Date()) return step();
it's not a good idea but just for debugging purpose. it seems that token is expired and not refreshing again.

Comment: The debug returns true on my computer, but it doesn't reach the the code on my server. It throws an exception beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that your auth credentials are missing or are incorrect. You should react on possible errors in the `useServiceAccountAuth` callback as well.

```
var filePath = filePrefix+"/some/filePath.json"; // <- correct credentials?
doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds, function (err) { 
  if(err) // handle error, you should see whats wrong
});
```

Comment: I think that helped me in the correct direction. I've logged the new exception, which looks like it is the authorization, which is the problem.